# How to solve this math puzzle with Python?

Tags: python, math, equation

```
   A + B = 8
   B + D = 8
   A + C = 13
   C - D = 6
```

How to find the values of A, B, C and D?

I assumed the values would be integers and positive and did this:

```
   a = range(0,14)
   b = c = d = a
   for i in a:
     for x in b:
      for y in c:
        for z in d:
          if (a[i] + b[x] == 8 and a[i] + c[y] == 13 and b[x] + d[z] == 8 and c[y]-d[z]==6):
            print(a[i],b[x],c[y],d[z])
```

But that does not work. Even then I extend range to `a = range(-100,100)`.
After solving the equation by hand (with Google's help) I know that floats are involved, e.g. `A = 3.5` etc.

But then how to solve it with Python.

Comment: When you do `i in list`, `i` gets the elements of the list, not the indexes. You don't need to do `a[i]`, just use `i`.

Comment: If the results can be floats, you can't do it with a search, because there are practically an infinite number to search. You need to use logic to solve it.

Comment: For instance, `A+B = 8` and `B+D = 8` implies that `A == D`

Comment: Use `numpy.linalg.solve()` function.

Comment: Python has many ways to solve that, because there are many ways to solve a system of linear equations. Please tell us the mathematics that you know then we can tell you of an appropriate solution. Do you know matrices, including taking their inverses and/or determinants? Do you know Gauss or Gauss-Jordan elimination? Or do you want a black-box solution (where you do not understand how it works)? Etc. As it is now your question is too broad.

Comment: That means you can replace `D` with `A` in the last equation, so you have `A + C = 13` and `C - A = 6`. You should be able to use high school algebra to solve that.

Comment: Add all the equations to get A+B+C = 17.5

Comment: @RoryDaulton hehe I've heard of all that stuff many many years ago (10 - 20 years I don't remember) :( ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to learn matrix theory (at least not for this).

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('A  B C D')
(A, B, C, D)
>>> solve([A+B-8,B+D-8,A+C-13,C-D-6])
{B: 9/2, D: 7/2, C: 19/2, A: 7/2}
```

You just need to express each equation such as A+B=8 in the form A+B-8=0 and then omit the '=0' part.

Comment: To be honest that's the kind of answer I hoped for because that's exactly what I as "just a user" not a developer love about Python - I don't need to reinvent the wheel! To almost any problem there seem to be an library that solves it.

I want to mark this answer as the accepted one because this approach is so intuitive even for beginners and does not require to know about matrices or to be great in math (though matrices obviously look cool and impressing!). Thank you Bill!

Comment: You're most welcome, Tset. Now I wish I could claim that any part of sympy was my own work. But I'm just a user myself.

Answer (score 8):

If you know linear algebra, you can frame the question as a system of equations, which is then trivial to solve using a freely-available and popular library called `numpy` (hat tip @Griboullis):

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 1, 0, 0], 
     [0, 1, 0, 1], 
     [1, 0, 1, 0], 
     [0, 0, 1, -1]]
b = [8, 8, 13, 6]
answer = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

If you want a refresher at the matrix math/linear algebra behind this python solution, you can check out https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-equations-matrices.html.

Comment: holy s*** ... that blows me away! I go and have a refresher on matrices :)))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It impresses me but I have to give preference to Bill's answer because of it's simplicity. Please check my comment below Bill's answer.